# UserControl within a ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, telerik, controltemplate

I have a ControlTemplate for a Telerik Tile and I am overriding like below:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ctrl:Tile}">
    <Border>  

        <local:UserControl>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>
        </local:UserControl>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

My user control looks like:

```
    <DockPanel>
        <!-- some content -->

        <ContentPresenter/>

    </DockPanel>
```

The ControlTemplate does not display the content of the UserControl.

If I change my control template to:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ctrl:Tile}">
    <Border>  
        <StackPanel>
            <local:UserControl/>

            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>
       </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

It will find the content and place it appropriately.  It seems like the ControlTemplate cannot find the content once it's nested inside my UserControl.  Is there anything I could be doing wrong?

Note that these ControlTemplate Items are appearing in an ItemsPresenter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're treating the `UserControl` as if it is a basic `ContentControl` (like a `Button`) which is a little different than what it actually is. Using `Button` as an example, when you add a child (i.e. a `TextBlock`) into a `Button` element that's actually setting that `TextBlock` as the `Button's Content` property. The way it gets rendered is through the `Button`'s `ControlTemplate`, which includes a `ContentPresenter` to inject `Content` into. The Visual Tree ends up like this:

```
<Button>
  -start Template
  <Border>
    <ContentPresenter>
      -start Content
      <TextBlock>
```

So far that's basically the model your code is following. The problem is that you're using a (still `ContentControl` derived) `UserControl` instead, which rather than using a `ControlTemplate` is most often defined with a XAML+code-behind model, where the XAML defines the `Content` of the `UserControl`. (It is possible to switch these models and template a `UserControl` or make a `Button` derived class with XAML+code-behind but not common)

If you want to both define the look of your `UserControl` in XAML as normal and still be able to inject other content you can add another `DependencyProperty` that mirrors the setup of the Content property and set your content to that. This approach is used with `HeaderedContentControl` derivatives (i.e. `Expander`) which essentially has 2 content properties, `Content` and `Header`. Using the new property would look like this:

```
<Border>  
    <local:UserControl>
      <local:UserControl.OtherContent>
          <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>
      </local:UserControl.OtherContent>
    </local:UserControl>
</Border>
```

And then inside the `UserControl`'s XAML you need to explicitly set up the `ContentPresenter` Bindings (you only get them for free inside templates of `ContentControls`):

```
<DockPanel>
    <!-- some content -->

    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=OtherContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
</DockPanel>
```

If you want a `ContentTemplate`, `ContentTemplateSelector`, or `ContentStringFormat` you'll also need to add properties and bindings for those.